# join 2 tables with SQL

Tags: sql

I have to join 2 tables with SQL in a special way:

TABLE1 has the fields GROUP and MEMBER, TABLE2 has the fields GROUP and MASTER.
I have to build a new TABLE3 with the fields GROUP and ID by copying TABLE1 to TABLE3 and search TABLE2 if there is a GROUP from TABLE1 and if, copy GROUP and MASTER to TABLE3.

Example:

`table1`:

```
group  member
1      a
1      b
1      c
2      x
3      y
```

`table2`:

```
group  master
3      n
3      z
1      k
9      v
2      m
7      o
8      p
```

Expected result, table3:

```
group  id
1      a       from table1
1      b       from table1
1      c       from table1
1      k       from table2
2      x       from table1
2      m       from table2
3      y       from table1
3      z       from table2
3      n       from table2
```

I hope everything's clear.

So what is the SQL query?

Thanks, Hein

Comment: Have a look at "union".

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The first part (copy members) should be easy:

```
INSERT INTO table3 (group, id) SELECT group, member FROM table1;
```

Then You just copy the masters, that are in groups, that are already present in `table1`:

```
INSERT INTO table3 (group, id) SELECT group, master FROM table2 WHERE group IN (SELECT DISTINCT group FROM table1);
```

Comment: No need for that DISTINCT in the sub-query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. Of course you need to INSERT the whole selection to your new table named Table3.

```
WITH TABLE1(GRP,MMBR) AS
 (SELECT 1, 'a' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'b' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'c' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'x' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'y' FROM DUAL),
TABLE2(GRP,MSTR) AS
 (SELECT 3, 'n' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'z' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'k' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 9, 'v' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'm' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 7, 'o' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 8, 'p' FROM DUAL)

SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT GRP, MMBR ID FROM TABLE1

  UNION --UNION ALL if you need duplicates

  SELECT GRP, MSTR ID FROM TABLE2
  WHERE TABLE2.GRP IN (SELECT GRP FROM TABLE1)
  )
  ORDER BY GRP, ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `UNION ALL` and 2 simple `SELECT` in an `INSERT` as follows:

```
INSERT INTO table3(group,id) 
SELECT group,id FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT group,id FROM table2
SELECT * FROM table3;
```

And if you don't want duplicate values,try this using `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL`:

```
INSERT INTO table3(group,id) 
SELECT group,id FROM table1
UNION
SELECT group,id FROM table2
SELECT * FROM table3;
```